# Not sure how this code reads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm browsing github looking at cool code, but don't understand what this code does:

I understand that there are 2 belongs_to associations, but I don't understand what the 'self.request' method means and what it does.

Also, isn't 'transaction' meant for SQL database queries and not ruby code?

Could someone please clarify?

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "friend_id"
  belongs_to :user


   def self.request(user, friend)
      unless user == friend or Friendship.exists?(user, friend)
          transaction do
              create(:user => friend, :friend => user, :status => 'requested')
              create(:user => user, :friend => friend, :status => 'pending')
          end
      end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your two questions:

1. `self.request` means the method is a class method. It is called on the class like `User.request(user_a, user_b)`. Whereas instance methods (defined without `self` are  usually instance method that are called on a specific instance of an `User`.
2. `transaction` is used to run queries in a database transactions. Note the two `create` method calls in the `transaction` block. They generate SQL inserts.

Answer (score 3):

`def self.request` means it's class method, i.e. you can call it `Friendship.request(user1, user2)`.

In it we check if it is not the same user, or the friendship already exists.

If not, we create 2 records in `frienships` table, wrapped in transaction. I.e. if any insert fails - no insert occurs.